# How to open a fragment in a Activity(non-AppCompatAcitivity)?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments, android-activity

as the title states, i would like to open a Fragment, that is located in an Activity(Non AppCompatActivity)

**Code:**

```
TableFragment fragment = new TableFragment();
  fragment.setArguments(bundle);
  View view = (View) findViewById(R.id.Example);
  AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) view.getContext().getApplicationContext();
  FragmentTransaction ft = activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
  ft.replace(R.id.idFragment, fragment);
  ft.commit();
```

**Error: Caused by:**

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
```

**Also tried:**

```
Activity activity = (Activity) this;
FragmentManager fragmentManager = activity.getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft= fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
TableFragment fragment = new TableFragment();
ft.replace(R.id.idFragment, fragment);
ft.commit();
```

**Error:**

```
Required type: androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction
Provided: android.app.FragmentTransaction
```

**Question:** How can i open a Fragment in an Activity (Non AppCompatActivity) ?

Comment: `TableFragment` is extending the AndroidX edition of `Fragment`. The activity that hosts it needs to extend from the AndroidX `FragmentActivity`. `AppCompatActivity` does this, but you could extend from `FragmentActivity` yourself. If you do not wish to do that, then your activity cannot display `TableFragment`.

Comment: do you mean your activity extends Activity?

Comment: @CommonsWare, Thank you it worked. Repost your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TableFragment` is extending the AndroidX edition of `Fragment`. The activity that hosts it needs to extend from the AndroidX `FragmentActivity`.

`AppCompatActivity` does this, but for some reason you do not wish to use it. That is fine, as you could extend from `FragmentActivity` yourself.

If you do not wish to do that, then your activity cannot display `TableFragment`. You would need to have `TableFragment` extend the framework edition of `Fragment`, which is deprecated.